# Alternative to VLookUp that can check if two factors are true

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I am wondering is there any alternative to VLookUP() that can check two factors before returning a value. I want to search for an identifier that is only unique for a given date.

I.E the Key exists multiple times in the dataset but only once for each date so the date and the key combined form a primary key.

Note: I want to do this without adding a column to the dataset.

[image]

This is a simplified example. I want a formula that will return 304 if I look up using 02/03/20 and 89076.

My current solution is to make another column that concatenates column A and column B and then do a Vlookup on the column but I am looking for a solution that does not require adding another column.

Using Excel 2010

Comment: What version of Excel are you running *and* please update the question with some sample input data, your current attempt and desired output.

Comment: I've made those changes

Comment: Dates will always be in ascending order?

Comment: Looks like you could use `SUMIFS`

Comment: Yes always, data is being added on an ongoing basis

Comment: No so in the real world example I'm not actually looking for a figure, it is a string I am looking for

So in the example above maybe "EUR" would be more applicable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel 2010, if you not looking for a figure but actual text, try the following:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1,INDEX((A:A=DATEVALUE("02/03/20"))*(B:B=89076),),0))
```

Comment: You are welcome @ConorCasey. Beware that I used whole-column references. You might want to use this sparsely to prevent the array formulas from affecting performance too much, or be more explicit about ranges you refer to.